# cross-platform keyboard handling

Tags: c, winapi, keyboard, cross-platform

How can we rewrite the following function/mechanism to work in cross-platform environments?

```
BOOL WasKeyDown(KEY_CODE key)
{
    if (0x00000001 & GetAsyncKeyState(key))//least significant bit is high
        return TRUE;                          //key WAS down
    else return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Input is inherently platform-specific. The CRT and Standard Library do not provide that level of control.

Comment: @IInspectable, that means, I need to use POSIX libraries?

Comment: To my knowledge, there's not even anything in POSIX, that allows you to query the keyboard state. You'll have to go below that as well, i.e. talk to the OS. Nothing that can be done in a cross-platform way. Either provide implementations for each target platform, or use a library that already does.